# Ошибка LNK1105 при компиляции в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

При компиляции c++ кода в VS 19 выводит ошибку LNK1105

что сделать чтобы исправить ?

[image: Та самая ошибка]

Comment: Возможно у Вас запущен `Project1.exe`.

Comment: не проблема не в этом

Comment: А раньше всё было ок? Или Вы только установили студию? Попробуйте пересобрать всё решение. Вот ёще [ссылка](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/444037/vs-2017-error-lnk1105-cannot-close-file.html)

Comment: Раньше все было ок. Студия стоит уже больше 6 месяцев по-моему.
Если пересобрать решение то это помогает но на 2-3 компиляции.